# add to associative array

Tags: php

I have some xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <data>
<items>
    <item><timestamp>2011-07-11T09:01:42Z</timestamp><title><![CDATA[ some data here ]]></title><link>http://twitter.com/aurl</link></item>
    <item><timestamp>2011-05-11T09:01:42Z</timestamp><title><![CDATA[ some data here ]]></title><link>http://twitter.com/aurlhere</link></item>
</items>
```

and I'm trying to loop over it and add it to an array:

```
 foreach($xml->items->item as $e) {
              $feedData['timestamp'] = $e->timestamp;
            $feedData['title'] = $e->title;
            $feedData['link'] = $e->link;
            $feedData['type'] = $e->type;
        }

    print_r($feedData);
```

The xml is there and if I put an echo in the foreach I get back 10 responses (whcih are how many items I have) but when I print the array out all I get is one line (which is the last entry in the xml doc).

```
Array ( [timestamp] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 2011-07-08T08:05:19Z ) [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => http://twitter.com.aurl ) [type] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
```

I suspoect I'm overwriting the array on each loop. But why ? It should be adding to the array. Sorry my php isn't great...hence what Is suspect is a bit of a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is only one `$feedData` array and you are always setting the value for some specific keys, e.g. `$feedData['timestamp']`. How do you think this should *add* to the array? Keys are unique, the same key cannot appear twice, so yes, you are just overwriting the values.

It seems you want an array of arrays:

```
$feedData = array();

foreach($xml->items->item as $e) {
    $feedData[] = array(
        'timestamp' => $e->timestamp;
        'title' => $e->title;
        'link' => $e->link;
        'type' => $e->type;
    );
}
```

Have a look at the [array manual *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more information about arrays.

Comment: Yes this is what I needed. I'm adding to the array at different stages so this is most suitable I think.

Answer (score 4):

```
 $i = 0;
 foreach($xml->items->item as $e) { 
   $feedData[$i]['timestamp'] = $e->timestamp;
   $feedData[$i]['title'] = $e->title;
   $feedData[$i]['link'] = $e->link;
   $feedData[$i]['type'] = $e->type;
   $i++;
 }

print_r($feedData);
```